# SQL Server : scalar function returns nothing, but it should return INT

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, triggers, insert

This is my function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fu_order_customer_adress (@customer_ID INT)
RETURNS INT AS
    BEGIN
        RETURN (
            SELECT c.adress_ID FROM customers AS c
            JOIN orders AS o ON (c.customer_ID = o.customer_ID)
            WHERE c.customer_ID = @customer_ID)
    END
```

It is used in `AFTER INSERT` trigger of table `orders`, which has following structure (without unimportant columns):

```
orders (order_ID INT, customer_ID INT, employee_ID)
```

`order_ID` is the primary key, the other columns are foreign keys.

Trigger looks like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_orders_insert ON orders
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @order_ID INT = (SELECT order_ID FROM INSERTED);
    DECLARE @customer_ID INT = (SELECT customer_ID FROM INSERTED);

    UPDATE orders
    SET adress_ID = (SELECT dbo.fu_order_customer_adress(@customer_ID))
    WHERE order_ID = @order_ID;
END
```

Following inserts are numbered to be later easily pointed to.

(**1**) This works fine for inserts with different `customer_ID`:

```
INSERT INTO orders(customer_ID, employee_ID) 
VALUES (1, 1)

INSERT INTO orders(customer_ID, employee_ID) 
VALUES (2, 2)
```

(**2**) But when order with already used `customer_ID` is inserted, insert will end with error:

```
INSERT INTO orders(customer_ID, employee_ID) 
VALUES (1, 2)
```

I figured out that it's caused by that function used in trigger, because in this case it returns nothing.

I tried to put `SELECT function` and `SELECT` used in function into trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_orders_insert ON objednavka
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @order_ID INT = (SELECT order_ID FROM INSERTED);
    DECLARE @customer_ID INT = (SELECT customer_ID FROM INSERTED);

    SELECT c.adress_ID 
    FROM customers AS c
    JOIN orders AS o ON (c.customer_ID = o.customer_ID)
    WHERE c.customer_ID = @customer_ID)

    SELECT dbo.fu_order_customer_adress(@customer_ID)

    UPDATE orders
    SET adress_ID = (SELECT dbo.fu_order_customer_adress(@customer_ID))
    WHERE order_ID = @order_ID;
END
```

In (**1**) are both `SELECT` results same.

In (**2**) is `SELECT` result ok, but `SELECT function` returns nothing.

I don't understand what's wrong...thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

For your this simple trigger I dont think you need this Performance killer Scalar function you can simply do the following without using any Scalar functions and simply joining your tables with Inserted table .

Also you have major issues with your logic in your trigger, it will only work for a single insert and will fail if there are multiple Inserts in your Orders table. A much safer and performance efficient approach would be something like .......

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_orders_insert ON orders
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE O
       SET O.adress_ID = C.adress_ID
    FROM orders O 
    INNER JOIN inserted  AS I   ON O.order_ID    = I.order_ID 
    INNER JOIN customers AS c   ON C.customer_ID = I.customer_ID         

END
```

Comment: 1) I'm also writting the information system app for this DB, where aren't any multiple inserts...but of course you are right, this is not safe. 
2) I will try that `JOIN` with `inserted` table, thank you. But why does my function behave like I have described?